Why ContentAsset deployment doesn't change the file?
We are trying to deploy Content Asset file update using the deployment but looks like it doesn't work. We can see updated details on Content Asset but actual image file is the same and doesn't have any updates, even the last modified data is not changed.
Why ContentAsset deployment doesn't change the file?

Documentation mentions about versions property of the Content Asset metadata file.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_contentasset.htm

versions  ContentAssetVersions    Required. Captures basic information
about the file version included the asset metadata. Typically the file
has only one version.

The person who was working on this, didn't retrieve the full Content Asset metadata file, so the versions property wasn't updated and this was the reason why image hasn't been updated on deployment

